# Nested Sql queries function effect PHP Transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I am going to write a long sql transaction and thinking to write reusable sql function so my question is that can i write the transaction in this fashion?

```
try {
    // First of all, let's begin a transaction
    $db->beginTransaction();

    // A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
    $db->query('first query');
    UpdateEmp();
      //anothre sql query function, i put him in another function so that i 
      //can use it seperately

    $db->query('second query');

    UpdateProject();

    $db->query('third query');


    // If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
    // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // An exception has been thrown
    // We must rollback the transaction
    $db->rollback();
}
```

whereas other sql functions will be like

```
  function UpdateEmp(){
     //separate sql queries for emplyee update
        UpdateEmpProject();//nested sql query function
    //Do any db error will stop and rollback the trasaction?
    }

function UpdateEmpProject(){

    //sepeate sql queries for emplyee update

    }
```

My question is that, will the transaction rollback if any error occurred in UpdateEmp function? Suppose UpdateEmp() also contain another function with sql query, then the nested query will also effect the transaction result?

Comment: Yes you can, that is the way its done

Comment: Will transaction detect the db exception and it will rollback all the work?

Comment: If PDO is set to `->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and you catch (PDOException) rather than Exception

Comment: No it is not working. when nested query becomes fail it didn't rollback.